# Picasso with a lot of big bitmaps in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, android-listfragment, picasso

I have a question about a Picasso library. I am having the ListView in ListFragment to download images from server. I am using BaseAdapter to populate that ListView. The problem is that when I come to big number of images (10+) I am havibng the loading issues when picasso tries to load them. Basically I have to wait a bit before they load and suddenly they all load at once. This happens only when I go to another activity and return to MainActivity with this fragment Here is my sourcecode for baseAdapter:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;
private final double[] lat2;
private final double[] lon2;
private final double lat;
private final double lon;
private final int[] id;
private final int[] timestamp;
private final int[] likes;
private final String[] tags;
private final String[] statusText;
private final String[] imgLink;
private final String[] author;


public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values, double[] lat2,double[] lon2,double lat, double lon, int[] id,int[] timestamp,int[] likes, String[] tags,String[] statusText,String[] imgLink, String[] author) {
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.lat2 = lat2;
    this.lon2 = lon2;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.id = id;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.statusText = statusText;
    this.imgLink = imgLink;
    this.author = author;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(lat2!=null){
    return lat2.length;}
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    try {

    int distance = 0;
    if (lat2 != null && lon2 != null) {
        distance = (int) computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(lat, lon), new LatLng(lat2[getCount()-position-1], lon2[getCount()-position-1]));
    }
    ImageButton like = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            likeStatus(id[getCount()-position-1],author[getCount()-position-1]);
        }
    });
    TextView firsteLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.StatusText);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.StatusImage);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String author1 = null;
            String link = null;
            String text3 = null;
            String tags1 = null;
            int distance = 0;
            int ts = 0;
            int id1 = 0;
            int likes1 = 0;
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            id1 = id[getCount()-position-1];
            likes1 = likes[getCount()-position-1];
            author1 = author[getCount()-position-1];
            link = imgLink[getCount()-position-1];
            text3 = statusText[getCount()-position-1];
            if (lat2 != null&&lon2 != null) {
                distance = (int) computeDistanceBetween(ll, new LatLng(lat2[getCount()-position-1], lon2[getCount()-position-1]));
            }
            else {
                distance=0;
            }
            ts = timestamp[getCount()-position-1];
            tags1 = tags[getCount()-position-1];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowMarkerContent.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id1);
            intent.putExtra("likes", likes1);
            intent.putExtra("tags", tags1);
            intent.putExtra("link", link);
            intent.putExtra("author", author1);
            intent.putExtra("text", text3);
            intent.putExtra("distance", distance);
            intent.putExtra("time", ts);
            intent.putExtra("number", getCount()-position-1);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
        Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(imageView);
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://files.guri.sk/" + imgLink[getCount()-position-1]).fit().centerCrop().error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).into(imageView);

        Log.d("Tag","http://files.guri.sk/"+imgLink[getCount()-position-1]);
    if (distance > 1000) {
        distance = distance / 1000;
        firsteLine.setText(values.get(getCount()-position-1) + " (" + MySearchAdapter.caluculateTimeAgo(timestamp[getCount()-position-1]) + ", " + String.valueOf(distance) + "km) ");
    } else {
        firsteLine.setText(values.get(getCount()-position-1) + " (" + MySearchAdapter.caluculateTimeAgo(timestamp[getCount()-position-1]) + ", " + String.valueOf(distance) + "m) ");
    }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    }

    return v;
}

public void likeStatus(int id, String user){
    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("user", user);
        toSend.put("id", id);
        JSONTransmitterLike transmitter = new JSONTransmitterLike();
        String resp = null;
        try {
            resp = transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[]{toSend}).get();
            resp = resp.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            Log.d("Tag", resp);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(resp);
        int numberOfLikes = jObj.getInt("like_total");
        int result = jObj.getInt("result");
        int liked = jObj.getInt("liked");
        if (result == 2) {
            unLike(id, user);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"You like this",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void unLike(int id, String user) {
    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("user", user);
        toSend.put("id", id);
        JSONTransmitterUnlike transmitter = new JSONTransmitterUnlike();
        String resp = null;
        try {
            resp = transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[]{toSend}).get();
            resp = resp.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            Log.d("Tag", resp);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(resp);
        int numberOfLikes = jObj.getInt("like_total");
        int result = jObj.getInt("result");
        int liked = jObj.getInt("liked");
        Toast.makeText(context,"You don't like this",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel the request only if this is a recycled view, not for every view.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Well, it has the same effect when I use this line and when I don't

Comment: Did you put "Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(imageView);" into the else? (when convertView is not null)?

Comment: I meant iit doesn't matter whether I use this line or not.The result is the same.